# Help to prove that this limit is 0

Tags: limits

Hello i have the following limit. $$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\log^kx}{x}\right).$$ I applied D.L rule but i don't know how to continue. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is $k$ ? an integer, a real, a complex number ?

Comment: a real which is >0

Comment: Try finding$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{1/k}}$$ first.

Comment: $\frac{\log^k x}{x} = \frac{u^k}{e^u} \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate
$$
L = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ { (\log x)^k \over x }
$$
we use a simple substitution
$$
u = \log x
$$

Then
$$
x = e^u
$$

When $x \rightarrow \infty$, $u \rightarrow \infty$.

Thus, we can simplify $L$ as
$$
L = \lim\limits_{u \rightarrow \infty} \ \left[ {u^k \over e^u} \right]
$$

Applying L'Hospital's rule repeatedly, we obtain after $k$ steps
$$
L = \lim\limits_{u \rightarrow \infty} \ {k! \over e^u} = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$\frac{\log^k(x)}{x}=\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt[k]{x}}\right)^k.$$
Try Hospital rule with
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt[k]{x}}.$$